# When grouped, how to sort by "groupingKey"?

Tags: slickgrid

I want to know if it's possible to sort by "groupingKey" while "dataView" is grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `groupingKey` for anything but the calls to `expandGroup()` or `collapseGroup()`.

To sort groups, specify a `comparer` in your call to `setGrouping()`.
See the example at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-grouping.html.